# Cloud masking on Landsat collection 2

Tags: google-earth-engine, cloud-cover, normalized-difference-water-index

I try to create a water map using NDWI from Landsat 5 and 8 collection 2. I face a problem in my result, which I think come from the Landsat-5 collection. I applied the cloudmask function like the tutorial for landsat-8 with some correction for the Landsat 5 as below. But there are still some unwanted result in the end like in the image below. Here is the link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/f35a201b3cae5d478e2a94d87d2e88bf
[image: incorrected pixels]

```
  // Landsat5
var cloudMaskC2L5 = function(image) {
  var dilatedCloud = (1 << 1)
  var cloud = (1 << 3)
  var cloudShadow = (1 << 4)
  var qa = image.select('QA_PIXEL');
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(dilatedCloud)
    .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloud))
    .or(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadow))
  var mask2 = image.mask().reduce(ee.Reducer.min());
  return image.updateMask(mask.not()).updateMask(mask2);
}
/ landsat 8
function maskL8sr(image) {

  var qaMask = image.select('QA_PIXEL').bitwiseAnd(parseInt('11111', 2)).eq(0);
  var saturationMask = image.select('QA_RADSAT').eq(0);

  // Apply the scaling factors to the appropriate bands.
  var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
  var thermalBands = image.select('ST_B.*').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);

  // Replace the original bands with the scaled ones and apply the masks.
  return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
      .addBands(thermalBands, null, true)
      .updateMask(qaMask)
      .updateMask(saturationMask);
}
```